# WordPress wp_head - how to add new script files to the top?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-4.3

How can I add my script files to the very top in the wp_head?

From this guide, using the code below will always add my new script file to the very bottom:

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_javascript');

function hook_javascript() {

    $output="<script> alert('Page is loading...'); </script>";

    echo $output;
}
```

Any ideas how I can move my new script files to the top?

Comment: Why would you want to put js at the top and why would you want it to be inline?

Comment: sorry, inline is just an example. it is a link. bcos the script files have to load first.

Comment: `wp_enqueue_script()`

Comment: I tried that. it add my new css/ js files at the bottom. how to push them up then?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Use the `$priority` parameter of the [`add_action()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) function.

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

> **$priority**
>   *(int) (Optional)* Used to specify the order in which the functions associated with a particular action are executed. **Lower numbers correspond with earlier execution**, and functions with the same priority are executed in the order in which they were added to the action.
>   *Default value: 10*

So, choose a very low number and as long as no other plugin/theme uses an even lower number your line will be added at the top.

```
add_action('wp_head','hook_javascript', -1000);
```

Answer (score 6):

```
function enqueue_assets()
{
    wp_enqueue_script('your_plugin_js', plugins_url('/my.js', __FILE__));
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_assets');
```

By default, this will put it in the header. If you change your mind in the future (and you should), you can pass `true` as fifth parameter of `wp_enqueue_script` and it will be placed at the bottom. Refer to the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) for more info on params.

Comment: I misunderstood your question a bit. Priority param should do the trick as author above has specified. Though there is no need to make it a negative value.